# axios api authentication headers jwt and security

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Two questions here:

1. I was not able to pass in a post request using axios and authorization headers as such:

   axios.post('http://localhost/dashboard', {headers: { 'Authorization': 'JWT xxxxxx' }})

But I was able to get it to work with a preset: `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT xxx'`

Am I missing something as to why the headers parameter was sending the "headers" as a data payload instead of as an actual header?

2. Once I generate a JWT from my login page, on each page request after that I am only showing the page if the response.status is 200. Is this the correct way to redirect someone back to a login page if their jwt is fake or invalid for accessing the page?

The flow is:

1. /login for user to get JWT
2. immediately directed to /dashboard but before they are an api call is made to /dashboard using the JWT and if status code is 200, then the /dashboard page is shown. Is this correct or should I be implementing something more than just a 200 code?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something as to why the headers parameter was sending the "headers" as a data payload instead of as an actual header?

1. Because you're passing the headers as the data payload. I suggest reading the axios docs for `axios.post()`
2. It's common to automatically refresh the JWT instead of logging the user out. Depends on your security requirements. For ex., if you were a bank, it's better to log the user out than to auto refresh the JWT.

Instead of checking for 200, check if the status is 403 (or whatever status your backend returns for an invalid JWT). If your backend errors (500), or receives a bad request (400), it's not relevant to an invalid JWT and you'd be logging the user out for nothing.